# Flink interval join throws error: Long.MIN_VALUE timestamp: Elements used in interval stream joins need to have timestamps meaningful timestamps

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have 2 KafkaConsumers A (topic = "viewTopic") & B (topic = "engTopic") and 1 KafkaProducer C (topic = "delayedTopic").

Events in A & B are strings of form `a_{id}_{timestamp}` and `b_{id}_{timestamp}` respectively.

I need to do the following:

1. Delay the events in A by 2 seconds
2. Do an interval join with events in B if their ids match
3. Push the joined events in C.

I'm using event time as interval join works on event time only.

#### Main class

```
public class DataStreamJob {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        Properties properties1 = new Properties();
        properties1.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties1.setProperty("group.id", "myGroup1");
        Properties properties2 = new Properties();
        properties2.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
        properties2.setProperty("group.id", "myGroup1");
        Properties properties3 = new Properties();
        properties3.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

        // set up Kafka String view consumer
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> viewConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("viewTopic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties1);
        DataStream<Event> delayedViewStream = env.addSource(viewConsumer)
                        // map incoming string to a JSON.
                        .map(DataStreamJob::parseEvent)
                        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                                .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getTimestamp()))
                        // records with same key are assigned same partition
                        .keyBy(event -> event.getId())
                        .process(new DelayedEventsProcessFunction());

        // set up Kafka String engagement consumer
        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> engConsumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("engTopic", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties2);
        DataStream<Event> directEngStream =  env.addSource(engConsumer)
                        .map(DataStreamJob::parseEvent)
                        .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.<Event>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                                .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getTimestamp()))
                        .keyBy(event -> event.getId());

        // interval join both streams
        DataStream<Event> joinedStream  = delayedViewStream.keyBy(event -> event.getId())
                        .intervalJoin(directEngStream.keyBy(event -> event.getId()))
                        .between(Time.seconds(-10), Time.seconds(10))
                        .process(new EventJoinProcessFunction());

        // set up Kafka Event producer
        KeyedSerializationSchema<String> keyedSerializationSchema = new KeyedSerializationSchemaWrapper<>(new SimpleStringSchema());
        FlinkKafkaProducer<String> kafkaProducer = new FlinkKafkaProducer<>(
                        "delayedTopic",
                        keyedSerializationSchema,
                        properties3,
                        FlinkKafkaProducer.Semantic.EXACTLY_ONCE);

        joinedStream.map(Event::eventToString).addSink(kafkaProducer);
        env.execute();
}
```

#### Code for DelayedEventsProcessFunction

```
public class DelayedEventsProcessFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<String, Event, Event> {
    private transient MapState<Long, Event> delayedEventsState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        MapStateDescriptor<Long, Event> delayedEventsDescriptor = new MapStateDescriptor<>(
                "delayedEventsState",
                Types.LONG,
                TypeInformation.of(new TypeHint<Event>() {})
        );
        delayedEventsState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(delayedEventsDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(Event event, KeyedProcessFunction<String, Event, Event>.Context ctx, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
        long currentTimestamp = event.getTimestamp();
        long delayedTimestamp = currentTimestamp + TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(2);
        // schedule a callback when 2 seconds have passed.
        ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(delayedTimestamp);
        delayedEventsState.put(delayedTimestamp, event);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
        Event delayedEvent = delayedEventsState.get(timestamp);
        if (delayedEvent != null) {
            out.collect(delayedEvent);
            delayedEventsState.remove(timestamp);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Code for EventJoinProcessFunction

```
public class EventJoinProcessFunction extends ProcessJoinFunction<Event, Event, Event> {
    @Override
    public void processElement(Event left, Event right, ProcessJoinFunction<Event, Event, Event>.Context ctx, Collector<Event> out) throws Exception {
        out.collect(new Event("join:"+left.getType()+right.getType(), left.getId()+right.getId(), left.getTimestamp()));
    }
}
```

#### Code for Event class

```
public class Event {
    private final String type;

    private final String id;

    private long timestamp;

    public Event(String type, String id, long timestamp) {
        this.type = type;
        this.id = id;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {return timestamp;}

    public String eventToString() {
        return String.format("%s_%s_%s", type, id, timestamp);
    }
}
```

#### Local setup

- Download IntelliJ for Mac
- Download latest Kafka: https://kafka.apache.org/quickstart
- `tar -xzf kafka_2.13-3.4.0.tgz`
- `cd kafka_2.13-3.4.0`

Create the 3 topics

- `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic viewTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`
- `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic engTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`
- `bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic delayedTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

Open 5 different terminals and run the following commands inside kafka_2.13-3.4.0 folder:

- `bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties`
- `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`
- Write events: `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic viewTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 < viewEvents.txt`
- Write events: `bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --topic engTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 < engEvents.txt`
- Read output: `bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic delayedTopic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`

viewEvents.txt and engEvents.txt will have strings of the form `view_{id}_{timestamp}` and `eng_{id}_{timestamp}` repectively. Each string will be in a new line. e.g `view_1_1683787256`, `eng_1_1683787456`

Run the code in IntelliJ and you are good to go.

Comment: Try applying assignTimestampsAndWatermarks after the 2 second delay.

Comment: Also, it's a bit worrisome that you are registering the timer for 2 seconds (in wall clock time) after the event's timestamp. That could be a time in the past.